# Modelling tide vs time with trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have been asked to collect tidal data (time and height) for a location over a seven day period to answer the following question...

"**Model the scenario using a single trigonometric function**.

- Plot the height verse elapsed time in a suitable graphing software and interpret the observable amplitude, vertical shift and period of the data set, to fit a trigonometric model to the data. Provide reasons for your choices."

I'm assuming they want a sinusoidal function that best fits the data since the minima and maxima, over the 7 day interval, vary quite a bit and cannot be accurately modelled with a single trig function.

However, the question later asks to predict heights of high and low tides at a future time, which will be difficult given the inaccuracy of the model.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: $a+b \sin(c\,t+d)$ is a trigonometric function

Comment: Hi Claude, thanks for your hint, however, I am already aware that +sin(+) is a trigonometric function.

Comment: I just wanted to mean that you have a large flexibility in terms of number of parameters. Did you collect data ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Apologies. Yes I have collected the data and have input into Desmos. However, when adjusting parameters A, B, C and D from the trig function Asin(Bx+C)+D, or the form you have provided, I cannot perfectly capture all the data points. I am assuming the question just wants me to fit a function as closely as possible? Do you agree?

Comment: This is a difficult problem. Could you post a data set ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a regression task.

We can't and we are not supposed to be able to through all the points due to the errors that you mentioned earlier. However, you can aim to minimize some sort of objective function.

If $(x_i, y_i)$ are your data points, then you can chosoe $A, B, C, D$ to minimize

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left( y_i - A-B\sin (Cx_i +D) \right)^2.$$

If you can fit the curve perfectly, the quantity will be positive but we just want the quantity to be as small as possible.

Furthermore, you might also want to get rid of outliers.

Comment: Thank you so much, that series works quite nicely. May I ask what it is and where you got it from? Sorry, I'm a novice.

Comment: We want to fit a curve, let say the graph of the fitted curve is $\hat{y}_i$, I am describing how to minimizing the sum of the difference squared, $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$